# WPA2 802.1X Wifi with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless

I go to a public place where a wifi connection is possible. It is a WPA2, 802.1X connection. I have a username and a password, but when I simply find that network under the regular 'Select Network' (in Ubuntu) and try to connect, it fails.

I'm looking for some kind of config file, where I can manually enter my username/password, but I can't find the needed config file. I found this https://www.nowiressecurity.com/configure-8021x-authentication-linux page, but it doesn't specify the exact location of the config file.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Network802.1xAuthentication the configuration is located on `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`— IIRC the newer Ubuntu distribution require to install `wpasupplicant` packages.

```
sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

Then you can start editing the configuration files.

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

---

You can also create a new connection through Ubuntu's `network-manager`, then changes the WiFi security to **`Dynamic WEP (802.1X)`**.

[image]

More information regarding this method would be in this Youtube videos → https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEDNtJE6ZDc

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ll check it out.